# How to convert a string in a number PHP

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have a Foreach where I have two variables ($num1 and $num2) as string. I'd like to covert them as number (integer should be ok).

This is my code:

```
    ...
    foreach ($titles as $match) {
    list($num1, $num2) = explode(':', $results[$c++]->innertext); // <- explode

    echo "<tr><td class='rtitle'>".
    "<td class='last-cell'>".$match_dates[$c]->innertext . "</td> " .
            //"<td class='first-cell tl'>".$match->innertext."</td> "  .   
            " - ".$match->innertext." ".$num1.':'.$num2 .  "  "   .     
            "<td class='odds'>".$best_bets[$b++]->attr['data-odd'] . ";" .
            "".$odds[$b++]->attr['data-odd'] . ";" .
            "".$odds[$b++]->attr['data-odd'] . "</td>" .

            "</td></tr><br/>";
}
...
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Thanks for your answer. I am going to explain and maybe you could help me: I have a a problem with `best_bets` value, because it's not alway before odds variable, so I was thinking to use "if statement", where I can fix some rules: when `$num1` is `> $num2`, I will show an echo order; when  `$num1` is `= $num2` another echos order and. at least,  `$num1` is `< $num2` another echos order. But to do this, I need to convert  $num1 and $num2 to do it. I hope to be clear. Thank you for your helping

Comment: PHP does [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), so it might not be needed to convert it (depending on what you would like to do of course).

Comment: Why convert `$num1` and `$num2` into integers?  You only ever use them to build a string (your HTML output) so leaving them as a string works.  You don't even need to explode them on `:` since you re-concatenate them with `:` in the middle anyways.  Confused am I.

Comment: I edited my question, please check and, if you can, help me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cast them to an int:

```
$num1 = (int) $num1;
```

Or use the [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function:

```
$num1 = intval($num1);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I see now that I miss some values in my echo when $num1 and $num2 are both = 0. Any suggestion? thanks